# SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll() does not cancel

Tags: vb.net, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer

I have a button on my form that is labeled Speak, when user clicks on it `synth.SpeakAsync(Textbox.text)` is fired, and the button changes its text to "Stop Speaking".

However when a user clicks on stop speaking, thereby firing the `synth.speakAsyncCancelAll()` it doesn't cancel the speech mid text.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
Private Sub btnSpeak_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSpeak.Click
    If RTextBox.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim synth As New SpeechSynthesizer
    synth.Rate = -2

    If btnSpeak.Text = "Stop Speaking" Then
        btnSpeak.Text = "Speak"
        synth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll()

    ElseIf btnSpeak.Text = "Speak" Then
        btnSpeak.Text = "Stop Speaking"
        synth.SpeakAsync(RTextBox.Text)
    End If
```

Comment: Have you checked that SpeakCompleted event is fired after cancellation ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasynccancelall(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click the button a new speech synthesizer is being created. Take the dim synth as new speech synthesizer out of the button click event. this way it will refer to the same synthesizer each time and it should then fire the speech cancelled event

Answer (score 0):

[SpeakAsyncCancelAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasynccancelall(v=vs.110).aspx) will raise the [SpeakCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event after being called, you can listen to it using the following code:

```
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim synthesizer As New SpeechSynthesizer()
        AddHandler synthesizer.SpeakCompleted, AddressOf speakCompleted
    End Sub

    Private Sub speakCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SpeakCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim cancelled = e.Cancelled
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: it is not firing the speech completed event until it finishes everything in the textbox

Comment: Well, I guess that it's the lowest common denominator you will get with this function. Maybe you can try Dispose() instead, you'll have to re-create the synthesizer every time, though.

Comment: Figured it out, every time i clicked on the button it was creating a new speech synthesizer so i took that variable out of the function, this way it will create the synth at the beg of running code and always refer to the correct one. Thank you for your help